# Rails starts with a long list of warnings concerning already initialized constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails starts with a long list of warnings concerning already initialized constants.
Here a list of the warnings

```
/Users/jochen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_LISTIO_MAX
/Users/jochen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_MAX
/Users/jochen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_PRIO_DELTA_MAX
/Users/jochen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_ARG_MAX
/Users/jochen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_ATEXIT_MAX
/Users/jochen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_BC_BASE_MAX
... and many more from the same ruby path
```

This doesn't seem to produce problems, but it's kind of annoying. Has someone an idea how to fix these warnings?

Comment: Try running `gem uninstall etc` and then `bundle update`.

Comment: Do  you use bootsnap in your rails application?

Comment: See if this https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/112 helps.

Comment: @max That was the solution. bundle update updated some gems to incompatible versions, but I could fix that. Can you please explain, what happens exactly in this solution, because I do not find the etc gem in the gemfile, neither before executing `gem uninstall etc` nor after `bundle update`.

Comment: A gem being referenced in your Gemfile is depending on `etc`, yet `etc` is probably installed globally; Add `etc` to your project gemfile, then run `bundle install` (or just `bundle`...it does the same thing) then the warnings should be gone

Answer (score 39):

`bundle update` and `bundle clean --force` worked when running into the same issue.

Comment: `bundle clean --force` – finally! thank you, this has been the missing puzzle piece for me

Comment: Worked for me. I needed to insert my root password during the `bundle update`, and use `sudo bundle clean --force` at the second stage. Perhaps this is due to my using sudo like this in the past. I only work with ruby every few years.

Comment: This definitely works for rails 6.1.4.1

Answer (score 4):

Switch the order of the top answer:

`bundle clean --force` and then `bundle update`

Comment: Hey. glad to see a new contributor. Please note that your answer is not bringing anything new to the table, so it is better just to upvote the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: In fact it brings in some confusion, as it indicates that `bundle update` should be executed as the *second* command :) Also note, to be fair, there is no *accepted* answer yet.

Comment: late coming to this, but this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

This happened for me while I was running tests. I tried `bundle clean --force` but nothing changed.

Closing and reopening my terminal fixed it. Restarting did too. The first one is easier.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it could be caused by a conflict between the global gems and the ones in the Rails project managed by bundler: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/112#issuecomment-483789081