# rails assets:precompile - LoadError: cannot load such file -- i18n/core_ext/hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mastodon

### Edit:

I have gone ahead and uploaded a minimum required example and published it to github for anyone looking to test
https://github.com/alilland/issue-1

---

Have an old project that I have inherited from 2018

in the dockerfile I see it runs the following:

```
# ...
# Precompile assets
RUN cd ~ && \
    OTP_SECRET=precompile_placeholder SECRET_KEY_BASE=precompile_placeholder rails assets:precompile
```

```
 > [stage-1 12/13] RUN cd ~ &&  OTP_SECRET=precompile_placeholder SECRET_KEY_BASE=precompile_placeholder rails assets:precompile --trace:
#24 0.420 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::RubygemsIntegration::EXT_LOCK
#24 0.420 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:12: warning: previous definition of EXT_LOCK was here
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::VERSION
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/version.rb:10: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/constants.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::WINDOWS
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:4: warning: previous definition of WINDOWS was here
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/constants.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::FREEBSD
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:5: warning: previous definition of FREEBSD was here
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/constants.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::NULL
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:6: warning: previous definition of NULL was here
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_MINOR_VERSIONS
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:12: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_MINOR_VERSIONS was here
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:27: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_MAJOR_VERSIONS
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:24: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_MAJOR_VERSIONS was here
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_PLATFORMS
#24 0.421 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:26: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_PLATFORMS was here
#24 1.859 rails aborted!
#24 1.859 LoadError: cannot load such file -- i18n/core_ext/hash
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chewy-5.2.0/lib/chewy.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler.rb:195:in `require'
#24 1.859 /opt/mastodon/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
#24 1.859 /opt/mastodon/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
#24 1.859 /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
#24 1.859 bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd ~ &&     OTP_SECRET=precompile_placeholder SECRET_KEY_BASE=precompile_placeholder rails assets:precompile --trace]: exit code: 1
make: *** [image] Error 1
```

It looks like the issue is appearing during `Bundle.require`

```rb
# /opt/mastodon/config/application.rb
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
# ...
```

Looking at my Gemfile.lock file i can see several things that depend on i18n

```
activesupport (5.2.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
capistrano (3.11.0)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
faker (1.9.3)
      i18n (>= 0.7)
i18n (1.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    i18n-tasks (0.9.29)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.2)
      ast (>= 2.1.0)
      erubi
      highline (>= 2.0.0)
      i18n
      parser (>= 2.2.3.0)
      rails-i18n
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      terminal-table (>= 1.5.1)
rails-i18n (5.1.3)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 6)
i18n-tasks (~> 0.9)
rails-i18n (~> 5.1)
```

any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Did you upgrade/install any gem ?

Comment: nope, its just been a few years since the project has been touched and i'm the new developer inheriting the project. trying to get it running. It was using docker, so at some point it used to work.

Comment: This is really weird because I can see that `chewy 5.2.0` is indeed requiring the `i18n` file here: https://github.com/toptal/chewy/blob/8967c249f0869077228ec0b4fb27ec7e85ad293a/lib/chewy.rb#L17 and the `i18n 1.6.0` has this file: https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/529b83a32036c210e4e35d49a2ac23e956cca67a/lib/i18n/core_ext/hash.rb

Comment: It could be corrupted cache or something similar (`bootsnap` has not always been stable) and I see that you've multiples warning about constant already defined maybe you could try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61904384/3097804

Comment: @SébastienP. i have gone ahead and uploaded a subset of the Docker + ruby files to replicate the issue -- running `bundle clean` doesnt help, Github link in the edit above